# WildFly server issue duplicate data sources

Tags: jboss, centos, wildfly, wildfly-10, wildfly-11

I'm running an application on WildFly server version 19.0.0.Final on CentOS 7. This application was working fine, but I run this almost 2 months later, and I'm getting this error where I didn't find any duplicate data sources in standalone.xml

> 14:21:06,641 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "application.war")]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [("deployment" => "application.war")]"
> 14:21:06,647 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace which you have provided, it seems the issue is related to the deployment and not related to the data source.

if multiple deployment-scanner are defined then make sure that they are pointing to different locations

If Multiple deployment-scanner would be defined pointing to the same path or parent directory's path, which results in multiple deployment attempts of the same war file causing the exception.